# Using an Observable next - Typescript syntax

Tags: typescript

How can I call the Observable next callback? I haven't used typescript much and I don't know where to find the syntax.

**Observer handler:**

```
  editingBudgetDate: BudgetDate;
  editSubscriptionHandler = function(observer: Observer<BudgetDate>) {
    observer.next(this.editingBudgetDate);
    observer.complete;
  };
```

**Subscribe to observable:**

```
onBudgetDateEdit(): Observable<BudgetDate> {
    const update = new Observable(this.editSubscriptionHandler);
    return update;
}
```

**Broadcast new subscription value (don't know how to)**

```
editBudgetDate(budgetDate: BudgetDate) {
    this.editingBudgetDate = budgetDate;


    //this.editSubscriptionHandler; < -- next()  not sure how to do this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can create the observable.

```
updateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>('')
public update = this.update.asObservable();
```

after then you can push your data into the

```
this.updateSubject.next({send data});
```

fetch this data using update variable

```
update.subscribe(data => {})
```